# How to write XCUI test for whether I navigate to correct screen or not?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am writing test UI test case for following UI 
[image]

I want to test on Login click whether I am navigating correctly on Dashboard screen or not.

Is there any method to do this?

My current testing code is like

```
func testExample() {

        let usernameTextField = app.textFields["Username"]
        usernameTextField.tap()
        usernameTextField.typeText("abc@gmail.com")

        let passwordTextField = app.textFields["Password"]
        passwordTextField.tap()
        passwordTextField.typeText("abc123")

        app.buttons["Login" ].tap()

                //let loginButton = app.staticTexts["Login"]
                //XCTAssertEqual(loginButton.exists, true)

        app.navigationBars["UIView"].buttons["Back"].tap()


    }
```

Answer (score 5):

UI Tests can become really fragile when depending on text values. What I encourage you to do is to set the Accessibility Identifier for your ViewController's `view`. That way, even if you change the title or change the whole layout, you can still be sure you're in the correct Page/Screen/View.

```
class DashVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.accessibilityIdentifier = "view_dashboard"
    }
}



    func test_login_withValidInput_goesDashBoard() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()

        //...    
        app.buttons["Login" ].tap()

        let dashBoardView = app.otherElements["view_dashboard"]
        let dashBoardShown = dashBoardView.waitForExistence(timeout: 5)

        XCTAssert(dashBoardShown)

    }
```

Comment: I think this is not sufficient answer/explination. I would like to suggest you, modify your answer with proper steps also if you can share the screenshot it will be great

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    app.buttons["Login - Login"].tap()
    XCTAssertEqual(app.navigationBars.element.identifier, "appname.CalculationView") //If your second view controller is SecondViewController, your identifier is appname.SecondView.Like that my second view controller is CalculationViewController so my identifier is CalculationView
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an accessibility indicator to the back button so you can check for availability using `backButton.exists` or `backButton.hittable` and assert accordingly. In any case, if you set

> continueAfterFailure = false

in setUp(), your test will fail as it is if it doesn’t find a button with “Back”.

Comment: Thanks for answer..but i want test case like...if i navigate to any screen just want to test if I am on correct screen or not without interacting with that screens elements...because back button can be available on screen on which i don't want to navigate

Comment: That was the reason for adding the accessibility identifier, so each element is uniquely identifiable

Comment: Do i need to add accessibility identifier programatically because in my UI it is created automatically as i am using navigation controller ..so i am not able to find way to put accessibility identifier in Storyboard

Comment: You can add it programmatically. I would add it to another distinct element though (instead of the backButton). Programatically you can just do `yourObject.accessibilityIdentifier = "YOUR_UNIQUE_ID"`

Comment: You could also do this for any element on the dashboard. The convention is to find a UI element unique to that screen and check it exists, so when you add components to your dashboard, pick one and check it exists so you don't have to rely on customising the back button.